# Sorting cell values in Excel respective to another value

Tags: excel

I have a scoreboard in excel which I need to sort. All pretty standard stuff so far, however I need to be able to rank the users on how far they are away from a certain number and not how big their score is. For example if I have a user with a score of 100 points, they are 100 points above 0. I have another user who has 0 points so they are 0 points away from 0. What I would like to do is assign player 2 with a rank 1 because they are closest to 0. I've tried googling the rank function in Excel but I can't find anything that does what I want to do. Anyone done anything similar in the past? And if so how did you get round it?

Comment: why not calculate your rank column near your data and sort by that column?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @rudym.

Say column A1:A20 has your player names, column B1:B20 their scores. In column C put

```
=B1 - 0 'or whatever number you want them to be closest to
```

then in column D put

```
=rank(C1,$C$1:$C$20,1)
```

to get your rank. Then just sort by your rank to get them in order.

Hope this helps!